# Issues with ionic Cordova and OneSignal

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

Please help me! I'm trying to enter push notifications with OneSignal without success. When I text my application in the xCode log it displays this:

````
WARN: Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin'
WARN: Native: tried calling OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin'
WARN: Native: tried calling OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin'
WARN: Native: tried calling OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin'
WARN: Native: tried calling OneSignal.endInit, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin' ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Found a temporary solution, just download an older version:

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.11.3
npm i @ionic-native/onesignal@5.31.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got same issue this topic and can make OneSignal works on IOS with these version of libraries:

```
npm i onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.11.3
npm i @ionic-native/onesignal@5.31.1
```

By the way, from Android SDK 33, the old extension doesn’t work, here is the log
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See   |  Android Developers for details.
Try with some newer version of those library and neither of them works

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 7.1.5 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.6.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics : 13.1.4
@angular/cli : 13.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI : 3.9.0
@capacitor/android : 5.0.5
@capacitor/core : 5.0.5
@capacitor/ios : 5.0.5

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed globally
native-run (update available: 2.0.0) : 1.5.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS : v16.20.1
npm : 8.12.1
OS : macOS Unknown
Xcode : Xcode 15.0 Build version 15A240d
```